# Create a TabControl fom codebehind at a clickevent of a button

Tags: c#, silverlight

On the **click event** of a button i have to **create two tabs** below the button.

```
private void bnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the tab control there already, with the Visible property set to false, and then set the Visible property to true in the button click event?

Comment: I followed thsi and i got it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is here :

**xaml :**

Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="SelectorDropDownButtonStyle"/>

```
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtFolderName" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="TextBox"  IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" />
             </Grid>

    <Controls:TabControl x:Name="tbc" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Controls:TabControl.Items >
                            <Controls:TabItem x:Name="brw" Header="Browse" Height="auto">
                    <Grid >
                            <Border x:Name="PopupOuterBorder" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="ReportSelectorOuterBorder"/>
                            <Border x:Name="PopupInnerBorder" Background="#404040" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="ReportSelectorPopupInnerBorder">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollBar"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="100" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="TreeScrollViewer" >
                            <Browser:FolderBrowser x:Name="folderPickerTree"   SelectionChanged="tree_SelectionChanged"    ></Browser:FolderBrowser>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                    </Grid>
            </Controls:TabItem>
            <Controls:TabItem Header="Search" Height="auto" >

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbSearch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="TextBox" TextChanged="SearchTextChangeEvent" />
                    <Button x:Name="bnSearch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="Button"  Click="bnSearch_Click" Content="Search"/>
                    <ListBox x:Name="displayfolderList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Height="30"></ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </Controls:TabItem>
        </Controls:TabControl.Items>       
        </Controls:TabControl>
```

**code Behind :**

public FolderPickerControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tbc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

private void bnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (IsDesignTime)
            return;
        brw.IsSelected = true;    
        if (tbc.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {

            tbc.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            tbc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

1. Create a TabControl user control with all of the tabs that you want to display.
2. Drag a place holder on your asp.net page, for example phTabHolder.
3. Add the user control to place holder control upon button click event, and show/hide the tab pages that you want to display. For instance, `phTabHolder.Controls.Add(m_UCtlMyTabControl)`

See [this for dynamically adding](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2009/10/aspnet-dynamic-controls.html) the a control.